# Что такое package в flutter?

Tags: flutter

Кто нибудь может простым языком обяснить что такое package в flutter и как package-установить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter поддерживает использование общих пакетов предоставленными другими разработчиками для экосистем Flutter и Dart. Это позволяет быстро создать приложение без необходимости разрабатывать все с нуля.

---

Добавим пакет (например css_colors) в наше приложение:

1. Заходим на сайт [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/)
2. В поиске находим необходимый пакет и заходим в него
3. Переходим по кнопке Installing (сверху)
4. Копируем `css_colors: ^1.0.2`
5. В проекте Flutter находим файл `pubspec.yaml`
6. Вставляем его после `dependencies` (обязательно сохраняем табуляцию):

> ```
> dependencies:
>   css_colors: ^1.0.2
> ```

7. Сохраняем файл и в терминале выполняем команду: `flutter pub get`
8. Используем его:

> ```
> import 'package:css_colors/css_colors.dart'; 
> ... 
> new Container(color: CSSColors.orange)
> ```

*[Источник](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages)*

Answer (score 1):

Package - это своего рода программа, которая решает определённую задачу. Для того чтобы вам не изобретать велосипед (то есть решать задачу, которая уже была решена кем-то до вас) вам предлагают воспользоваться пакетом.

Ставятся пакеты очень просто:

Для добавления пакета, `css_colors`, в приложение:

1. Откройте файл pubspec.yaml, расположенный внутри папки приложения, и добавьте css_colors под зависимостями.
2. Установить его:
   a) c терминала: `flutter pub get`
   или
   b) в Android Studio/IntelliJ: Нажмите `Packages get` в верхней части pubspec.yaml.
3. Импортируйте его добавив соответствующий оператор `import` в код Dart.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Остановить и перезапустить приложение, если необходимо.